# is there any other way to make backend in flutter without firebase

Tags: flutter, backend

currently, I am using firebase for the backend but is there any path I have to learn to do backend without using firebase since it's limited free

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create backend with nodejs and connect nodejs with your flutter app. There are plenty of resources for learning how to connect nodejs backend with flutter app

Comment: I have heard of node js before so by learning it I don't need anything else? I mean for backend of course

Comment: Yes. nodejs is basically used for backend.

Comment: Yes, you can do BE development with Java, Go, Python, NodeJS, Ruby, and many other things. Don't forget you also need a DATABASE for your BE. And this can be tedious if you are not familiar with it. Firebase saves your time and provide Full BackEnd infrastructure as a service. But if their features doesn't fit your needs, grab any other BE framework and code it as you like :)

Comment: you mentioned a lot of programming languages for backend Ik that there are no bad programming languages but according to your experience, you think that I should stick with node js?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Python, node js, PHP-laravel.. It depends on the projects. According to the project, you can choose the backend.

Answer (score 0):

"backend in flutter" ? , Flutter is framework in which we use dart programming language so the question is wrong. But perhaps you want to ask something else, which I was also exploring during my initial years.

1. For realtime database you can use mongo with polling (with or without even any server since you can even poll and crud in database with flutter itself).
2. For firebase cloud functions you either make your own APIs (with any backend say nodejs , Django , php..) and call them with Cron jobs or use mongo trigger.
3. For app performance monitoring , you first need to take data from your app itself and then store it in database and then need to make a web panel for showing that data in interactive manner.
4. Firebase hosting can't be your case so skipping it.

I hope that clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

try supabase or rethinkdb + rust